# will IF SIGNAL SQLSTATE in mariadb exit stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, signals, mariadb

I don't quite understand how MariaDB signals work.

I have a stored procedure that takes a string as input.  I am testing that string for valid characters.  If invalid characters are found then I want to send a signal that the error was invalid.  Will a stored procedure immediately exit if a `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '......' SET MESAGE_TEXT='......'`  is raised? Or will it  complete the procedure before issuing the signal?

Answer (score 1):

When just using `IF...THEN` statements it does not seem to work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testP`()
BEGIN
IF testStringSecurity('he;llo world') != 0 THEN
  SELECT 'INVALID CHARACTERS';
END IF;
SELECT 'GOOD TO GO'; 
END;
```

Always returns `GOOD TO GO`.  It seems that you must wrap in `IF ... THEN ... ELSE` like so to get a valid case.  Though setting a signal is different.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testP`()
BEGIN
IF testStringSecurity('he;llo') != 0 THEN
  SELECT 'INVALID CHARACTERS';
ELSE
  SELECT 'GOOD TO GO';
END IF;
END
```

Using a `SIGNAL` does seem to interrupt execution immediately.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testP`()
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
      @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT; 
        SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text); 
        SELECT @full_error;
END;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
BEGIN
  SELECT CONCAT('ERROR: ',@str,' RETRUNED NOT FOUND EXCEPTION.');
END;
IF testStringSecurity('he;llo') != 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '42000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ERROR: Invalid string';
END IF;

SELECT 'GOOD TO GO';
END
```

Returns `'ERROR 1644 (42000): ERROR: Invalid string'`